# unexpected '$twitter_handles' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) (Declaring array in Laravel controller)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to declare some arrays in a controller in Laravel 4.1, and I am receiving the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '$twitter_handles' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)
```

The code is below:

```
<?php

    class MiscController extends BaseController {

    $twitter_handles = array();
    $facebook_ids = array();

    $twitter_handles = array("@hello", "@there", "@you");

    $facebook_ids = array("122424", "12526", "123123");


        public function make_artists() {


            $length = sizeof($twitter_handles);

            $result = array();

            $i = 0;

            while($i < $length) {
                $result[$i]['fbid'] = $twitter_handles[$i];
                $result[$i]['twitter'] = $facebook_ids[$i];

                $i++;
            }

            echo $result;

        }

    }
```

I already used dump-autoload after making the controller.  I don't know why I'm receiving an error.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: try var $twitter_handles = array();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Class properties](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.properties.php) must be...

> ... defined by using one of the keywords *public*, *protected*, or *private*, followed by a normal variable declaration.

For example...

```
class MiscController extends BaseController {

    private $twitter_handles = ["@hello", "@there", "@you"];
    private $facebook_ids = ["122424", "12526", "123123"];
```

To use them in your class methods, you need to prefix them with the `$this` variable, eg

```
$length = sizeof($this->twitter_handles);
```

I strongly suggest you [read the fine manual](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.php).